# How can I set one command to be another command?

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a fairly silly situation here. Ubuntu does not ship proper packages so I was forced to find an external G++ package. Unfortunately the command to invoke g++ is now g++-5, not g++. I have an existing program that invokes `g++` through `popen` and similar functionality.

How can I permanently and globally set `g++` as an alias for `g++-5` for all possible access points, not just the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a softlink:

```
sudo ln -sf g++-5 /usr/bin/g++
```

Btw, Ubuntu is doing the same. `/usr/bin/g++` is also just a link to `g++-4.8`. You can check this using the following command:

```
readlink -f "$(which g++)"
```

Because of that I've added the `-f` flag to the above `ln` command. It will force `ln` to update the existing link.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use *debian alternatives*

https://superuser.com/questions/35275/ubuntus-etc-alternatives-mechanism
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-alternatives.8.html